# SQL - Create trigger after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have these four table that stores menus and the ingredients that if add a row to `customer_order` the `raw_material_quantity` from `raw_materials` should be automatically deducted based on the `quantity` from `menu_inventory` times the order_quantity from `customer_order`.

**Table menu**

```
+-----------+-----------+
| menu_code | menu_name |
+-----------+-----------+
|  prod-001 | Ice cream |
+-----------+-----------+
```

**Table raw_materials**

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| raw_material_code | raw_material_name | raw_material_quantity |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|     item-001      |       sugar       |          10           |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|     item-002      |       cream       |          20           |
+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Table menu_inventory**

```
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| raw_ingredients_number| raw_material_code | menu_code | quantity |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
|           1           |     item-001      | prod-001  |    5     |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
|           2           |     item-002      | prod-001  |    10    |
+-----------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Table customer_order**

```
+-------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
| customer_order_no |  customer_no | menu_name | order_quantity |
+-------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+
|         1         | customer-001 | Ice Cream |        2       |
+-------------------+------------- +-----------+----------------+
```

So I want to create a trigger to table `customer_order` after insert.
I already created one but it does not provide accurate results. Any answers will be a big help thanks.

**Edit**

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `customer_order_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `customer_order` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        declare x int;
        declare y int;
        declare quantity_1 int;
        declare quantity_2 int;
        declare sums int;

         if (select count(raw_material_code) from menu_inventory where  menu_code = new.menu_code > 0)
 then           
            set y = new.order_quantity;

            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temptable`;
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable (select row_number() over() as raw_ingredients_number,quantity,raw_material_code  from menu_inventory  where menu_code = new.menu_code);        
            while y > 0 do
            set x = (select count(raw_material_code ) from menu_inventory where menu_code = new.menu_code);
                while x > 0 do

                    set @mcode = (select menu_code from temptable where menu_ingredients_number = x);
                    set @rcode = (select raw_material_code from raw_material where raw_material_name  = @mcode);
                    set quantity_1 = (select raw_material_quantity  from raw_material where raw_material_name  = @mcode);
                    set quantity_2 = (select quantity from temptable where menu_ingredients_number = x);
                    set sums = quantity_1-quantity_2;

                    update raw_material set raw_material_quantity  = sums where raw_material_code  = @rcode;
                    set x=x-1;
                end while;

                set y=y-1;
            end while;

         end if;
    END
```

Comment: "I already created one but it does not provide accurate results" - that doesn't mean we wouldn't benefit from you showing us your attempt.

Comment: ok sir I'll edit

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many trigger implementations are product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh mysql 8.0

Comment: Please share the trigger you have implemented

Comment: @codeLover yes just a sec

Comment: i updated the question please take a look

Comment: please do bear with my code I am not good at it.

Comment: if (select count(raw_material_code) from menu_inventory where > 0)
 menu_code = new.menu_code then   is syntactically incorrect is there a transcription error here?

Comment: sorry it is supposed to be like this. if (select count(raw_material_code) from menu_inventory where  menu_code = new.menu_code > 0)

Comment: Next problem - is it really the case that raw_material_code is numeric in menu_inventory and char in raw_materials ? can they be changed to match? If not  how big an the int portion of the raw_material code in raw_materials grow?

Comment: my bad.. it's supposed to be varchar and  for now sir I haven't set a limit for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much cleaner method would be to use a multi-table update in the trigger

```
drop trigger if exists  `customer_order`;
delimiter $$
CREATE  TRIGGER `customer_order_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `customer_order` 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN
    update raw_materials r
        join menu m on m.menu_name = new.menu_name
        join menu_inventory mi on mi.menu_code = m.menu_code
            set r.raw_material_quantity = r.raw_material_quantity - (new.Order_quantity * mi.quantity)
        where r.raw_material_code = mi.raw_material_code;

 end $$

 delimiter ;
```